# MenuStrip not allowing to create menu

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm using visual studio 2019 and I created a windows form app project. In the form when I drop MenuStrip it is not showing me a box of Type here to create menus. I searched the internet but I don't get any solution. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

[image: See image here]

```
// Form1.Designer.cs

namespace asg_gui_F
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 24);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code of `Form1.Designer.cs`? Add it to the question.

Comment: Edited in the question.

Comment: .NET Core WinForms designer? Are you using a preview version?

Comment: Looks fine. Btw, I'm not familiar with new WinForms designer. But I suggest to add `winforms` tag to the question.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you are asking as I'm new to this domain

Comment: I've fixed that

Comment: @AhmadMuhammad: Expand the 'Properties' window (lower right corner). Now you will see a 'Dropdown' property, which you can click and create items.

Comment: If you point by mouse on the item TypeHere of menu, then the button of pop-up menu will be appear. If you open the menu (mouse click), then you can select one of three controls in menu :MenuItem – standard item of menu;
ComboBox – the item of “drop-down list” type;
TextBox – the control of “edit field” type.
In our case, we select first variant MenuItem.

Comment: It appears the problem you are having is because you have created a `.Net Core` application. From your comment… _”I searched the internet but I don't get any solution.”_ … and this is because “most” solutions are going to be using the `.Net Framework` NOT `.Net Core`. Unless you specifically need to use `.Net Core`, I recommend that you create a `.Net Framework` application, THEN, most solutions you search for will also be using the `.Net Framework`. It is unclear if you must use `.Net Core` and if you must, then refine your searches adding the `.Net Core` specification.

Comment: The winforms designer for .NETCore [is incomplete](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-on-net-core-windows-forms-designer/).  It is a big project.  Favor the ".NET Framework" project template until they are done.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure when you create a project you select "Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)" and you will see "Type here".

Comment: As with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4, the interface does not show the intended place holder.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out
instead of using core, use .netframework when creating forms

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed
in Visual Studio latest release **v16.10: 05/25/2021** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes). I have tested this both in net 5 (current) and net core 3.1 (LTS).

Demo:
https://youtu.be/3s55hWrHx4U

[image: Project setup]
[image: Image proof]

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been typically showing up in latest version of visual basic studio such as visual studio community edition 2019. Please perform following steps in VB 2019 .

1. Drag and Drop MenuStrip from Tool box
2. Right Click on Menu Strip ITEMS ->EDITS  - > Click on ADD ->Change name of text Property (eg: MyTest Menu)
3. Scroll Down to [DATA] Property -->Double Click on Drop Down Items Property
4. Click on Add  (Tool Strip menu items will be added) ->
5. Change the corresponding [text] property of sub item .

Answer (score -3):

- Click on new Project.
- Then Click on All Languages
- Then Select C# Language
- Then Click on Window Form App
- Then click on Create
- Then Choose your project name and location and click on the framework and make sure your framework is 4.0 then click on create.
- Then Click on create